# Can Nifi processor CaptureChangeMySQL handle hyphens in schema name pattern?

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi, cdc

Working with Nifi 1.3.0 and MySQL Server 5.7 for testing of CaptureChangeMySQL processor. Unfortunately, the schema I want to keep track of changes is hyphened like `schema-name-here.table_is_fine`, and the property "Database/Schema Name Pattern" in CaptureChangeMySQL processor can't understand it.

Does NiFi have a way to handle this kind of naming? I've tried `, ', and " but it seems to treat schema names with those quotations surrounding as unique to their counterpart without them.

Answer (score 2):

The *Database/Schema Name Pattern* field for the CaptureChangeMySQL processor expects a Java regex pattern string. From the [CaptureChangeMySQL processor documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-cdc-mysql-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.cdc.mysql.processors.CaptureChangeMySQL/index.html):

> A regular expression (regex) for matching databases (or schemas, depending on your RDBMS' terminology) against the list of CDC events. The regex must match the database name as it is stored in the RDBMS.

So, yes, it should be able to handle just about any schema name. Make sure you are using a valid regex pattern string, as internally, it will be passed to `Pattern.compile(YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME_PATTERN)`, where `YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME_PATTERN` is whatever you enter for the *Database/Schema Name Pattern* field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Might need to escape the pattern with `\-` because `-` has a specific meaning in regex compilation. Try `schema\-name\-here`.

Comment: HI Andy. Tried that escape style, but the same syntax error. I'll keep playing with it.